# Sending ControlValueAccessor-Component as Content in NgbModal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular7

*Note*: I have not added whole code because of simplicity. The code added is just to give an idea what I am looking for.

---

I have created a component that `implements ControlValueAccessor` like

Child

***TS***

```
export class ChildComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  // Other functions and variables

  myFunc() {
    // Somewhere in the class function
    this.propagateChange(this.myFormControl);
  }

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    // get initial value if any from parent component
    // this.myFormControl = initialValue;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {  }

}
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Child Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- Here we will deal with myFormControl. Also this section will propagate the change to parent component -->
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
  </div>
```

---

Parent

***TS***

```
// Top Form
this.formBuilder.group({
  'f1', [],
  'anArray': this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({ 'field1': [], 'field2': [], 'child': [// This will be sent to modal],
    this.formBuilder.group({ 'field1': [], 'field2': [], 'child': [// This will be sent to modal],
    ....
    ])
})

// Opening Modal
openChild(i: number) {
  // Get FromControl/FormGroup which is at the index of 'i'
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ChildComponent);
  // TODO: Here how can I assign formControlName to the ChildComponent ? <---------------------------
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="topForm">
    <input formControlName="f1" />
    <div formArrayName="anArray" class="mt-3" *ngFor="let value of anArray.controls; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i" >
        <input formControlName="field1" />
        <input formControlName="field2" />
        <!-- <app-child formControlName="child"></app-child> --> <!-- This child should be open in modal  -->
        <button (click)=openChild(i)>Open Child</button> <!-- this will assign child in the modal -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

`ChildComponent` is added as an `EntryComponents` of `NgbModal`.

Scenario

1) I have multiple children in a `FormArray` -- `'anArray'`.

2) Each `child` need to be shown in `NgbModal` when `Open Child` button clicked.

3) So for this I think the best practice is to open modal from TS code dynamically([like done over here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component)), but how can I assign `formControlName` to the `ChildComponent` modal ?

I am using Angular 7 and Reactive forms.

Comment: You need to see the modal as a different page, unrelated to the page opened in the main browser window. If you want a form in the modal, then put a form in the modal. But it will be a different form from the one displayed in the main window. You can't share a form control between the two forms. So, enter/edit whatever you want in the form in the modal, and when the modal is closed, pass the value of the modal form to the close() method. The main component, which opened the modal, can then get the value of the modal form and do whatever it needs to do with it.

Comment: @JBNizet If we just don't think of modal (at the moment). Don't you think `ControlValueAccessor` is use for same purpose ? Like we just pass formControl to child component and apply changes in child component then propagate the change to parent component **Seamlessly**. So why can't we achieve this behavior with `NgbModal` -- this will prevent us from writing lots of extra code ? Its like we can't or we shouldn't ?

Comment: A ControlValueAccessor is used to implement a component that can be used inside an Angular form (using ngModel or formControlName). Either this component is in the modal, or it's in the main component. It can't be in both at the same time.  Components form a tree. If a component is the child of the modal, it can't also be the child of the main component.

Answer (score 1):

Above comments from JB are very valid. I even think it's cleaner to just pass the form control to the modal, and when closed, pass the value of the form control to the calling component. Something like:

we pass the chosen formgroup to `openChild` from the template:

```ts
<div formArrayName="anArray" *ngFor="let value of anArray.controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <button (click)="openChild(value)">Open Child</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```ts
get anArray() {
  return <FormArray>this.topForm.get('anArray');
}

// Opening Modal
openChild(group: FormGroup) {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ChildComponent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.ctrl = group.get('child')
  // listen to the value from the modal
  modalRef.componentInstance.passCtrlValue.subscribe((value: string) => {
    group.get('child').setValue(value);
  })
}
```

The modal would take the form control as `@Input` and emit the value with `@Output`:

```ts
@Input() ctrl: FormControl;
@Output() passCtrlValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

close() {
  this.passCtrlValue.emit(this.ctrl.value)
}
```

In your template mark the formcontrol with `[formControl]`:

```html
<input [formControl]="ctrl">
```

Finally a **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygzgqa?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**